# One player controls the other unity photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, multiplayer, photon

Im creating a 3d multiplayer game and i started using photon. Everything was perfect until i tried to play online. When i enter from another device the variable view.IsMine changes automatically for some reason and the player in other device controls my player. Can someone help me please?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class Mototron : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = -21f;
    private float targetAngle = 90f;
    public float enemyK = 0f;

    public bool isMoving = false;

    public GameObject boxPrefab;
    public GameObject deadCanvas;
    public GameObject wonCanvas;
    public bool box;

    PhotonView view;

    void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }

    public void Update ()
    {      
        movement();
    }
    
    void movement ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && view.IsMine)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make that the devices control the exact player they are playing with!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm already fixed that, just destroy the other player camera if its not yours, like this

```
if(!view.IsMine)
{
  Destroy(cam);
}
```